# Getting 'object has no attribute' error although I did everything correctly

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-unittest, web-testing

Now, I have tried learning unittest in python to test websites from the techwithtim series on selenium.

I am trying to test the python.org website.

I am trying to run a test using unittest in Python. I have defined a ‘MainPage’ class that has a ‘click_go_button’ method. However, when I run the test, I get the following error message:

AttributeError: ‘MainPage’ object has no attribute ‘click_go_button’

I have checked my code for typos and missing methods, but I still can’t seem to figure out what’s causing the error. Can someone please help me troubleshoot this issue?

Here is the code for the ‘MainPage’ class:

```
class MainPage(BasePage):
    search_bar_element = SearchBarElement()

    def if_title_matches(self):
        return 'Python' in self.driver.title

    def click_go_button(self):
        element = self.driver.find_element(*MainPageLocator.GO_BUTTON)
        element.click()
```

MainPageLocator is a tuple that contains the locator of the go button in python.org

Here is how I used MainPage for the test .

```
class PythonOrgSearch (unittest.TestCase) :

    def setUp(self) : #runs each time a test_ function is run
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('https://www.python.org/')

    def test_test_also(self) :
        mainPage = page.MainPage(self.driver) #assigns the mainPage var to the return of MainPage returns (in case of mainPage bool)
        assert mainPage.if_title_matches #if mainPage.title_matches == True , test will continue                              
        mainPage.search_bar_element = 'pycon' #searches pycon
        mainPage.click_go_button()
        results = page.SearchResultsPage(self.driver)
        assert results.results_found()

    def tearDown(self) :
        self.driver.close()
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Thank you for your help!

I tried over a thousand times checking for any typos, problems with importing the MainPage, or any problem whatsoever. I asked Microsoft Bing a thousand and one times and even it was confused.

Comment: You're sure the `page.MainPage` you're loading in the test is the `MainPage` you've shown us, and not some other version of this file you have lying around?

Comment: I have mae manually a very limited amount of folders for programming . So , I think the answer is yes .